# CSS Colors in Stylesheet for a plug in (Genesis Enews)

Tags: css

I want to update the background color for the following following Genesis Enews Plug in. I updated the colors in the stylesheet, however when I hit refresh the colors don't change. It remains the same.  I am not sure what I a am doing wrong.

I want the following: 
Background - 34315c
Font Color- fdd87d
Button- fdd87d

Is there any other place that I need to change the color?

```
 /* Genesis eNews Extended
--------------------------------------------- */

.enews-widget {
    background: #34315C;
    color: #FDD87D;
    padding: 17px;
   text-align: center;
}

.enews-widget input {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    padding: 11px 17px;
 }

.enews-widget input:focus {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

.enews-widget input[type="submit"] {
     background: #8ECFB9;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }

 .enews-widget input:hover[type="submit"] {
        background: #8ECFB9;
        color: #ffffff;
 ;
 }

  .after-entry .enews-widget {
        margin-bottom: 37px;
  }

 .before-header .enews-widget .widgettitle,
 .before-header .enews-widget p,
 .content .enews-widget .widgettitle,
 .content .enews-widget p {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    line-height: 37px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    width: auto;
}

.before-header .enews-widget .widgettitle,
.content .enews-widget .widgettitle {
    font-size: 17px;
}

.before-header .enews-widget form,
.content .enews-widget form {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

.before-header .enews-widget input,
.content .enews-widget input {
    border: 0;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    width: auto;
}

 .before-header .enews-widget input[type="submit"],
 .content .enews-widget input[type="submit"] {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the html of the page -- the css doesn't make much sense without it, especially to those who have no idea what the Genesis Enews plugin looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Laura, we can't really tell without seeing ALL the CSS applied to the widget (which might even change over time, user interaction etc.). So my best advice to you is, **pop open the CSS inspector** (`CMD+SHIFT+I` or `CTRL+SHIFT+I*` on Firefox/Chrome, `F12` on Edge ...) and inspect the widget's tag that is supposed to show the colors. From there you'll be able to figure out why it doesn't work and what rule actually get's applied (look at the specificity).

Comment: I checked on a different browser and the colors changed. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Ok. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers which helps the community to separate useful from useless ones.